# Principled BSDF turns black when plugging in a normal map

Tags: materials, node-editor, normal-map

When using the Principled BSDF shader, plugging in a Tangent Space normal map will cause the material to turn black (yes, I've used the normal map node). Using object space or other alternative spaces changes the color of the material.

Comment: First, are you using non-color data. If not, do it. And if you are still having trouble, material nodes screenshot would be very useful.